# JQuery Plugin's Separate Scope for Each Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am developing a carousel jquery plugin. I am trying to call with more than one carousel div element like

```
<div class="carousel-container">...</div>
<div class="carousel-container2">...</div>
...
```

Where I am calling plugin

```
$(".carousel-container").mycarousel({
  // Properties
});

$(".carousel-container2").mycarousel({
  // Properties
});
```

Plugin Code:

```
(function($) {
   $.fn.mycarousel = function(options) {
      var settings = $.extend({
        indicators : true,
        autoplay : true,
        autoplayDir : "forward",
        slidesToShow : 1,
        slidesToScroll : 1
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      // JavaScript code like constructor function and its prototypes

      // variable declarations and initialization
      var outerCarouseWidth, imageWidth;
      var elements, carousel;
      ...

      // jquery code for selectors, events etc.
      var carouselInner = $(".carousel-inner");
      var carouselOuter = $(".carousel-outer");
      ...

      $(".next-link").on("click", function(e) {
            slide("next", "first");
      });
      ...
    });
   };
}(jQuery));
```

Well, right now I am trying to access child elements using $(this) within each function. Like $(this).children()[0].text("abc").

The Problem I am facing here is that, both carousel div elements are sharing the scope of variables, selectors etc. When I slide one carousel, other carousel moves as well and facing some other technical issues. How can I separate the scope of code of jquery plugin for each element with which I am calling this plugin?

Comment: What if you try this `$(this).find(".next-link").on("click", function(e) { ... ` ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scope the finding of elements to the current element that the plugin is applied upon.

Use carouselEl as the parent selector for all sub elements.

Like this:

```

```
return this.each(function() {
  var carouselEl = $(this);
  ...

  // jquery code for selectors, events etc.
  var carouselInner = carouselEl.find(".carousel-inner");
  var carouselOuter = carouselEl.find(".carousel-outer");
  ...

  carouselEl.find(".next-link").on("click", function(e) {

        slide(carouselEl, "next", "first"); // This must also be scoped.. I cant see the code for this function. 
  });
  ...
});
```

```

Comment: Should the settings be inside each function or outside? Like I have added it outside.

Comment: It can be outside like they are now. The settings are the same for each element applied with `mycarousel()`.